# Template Literals in React for bootstrap and css modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, templates

Hi I want to use *bootstrap* and *css modules* **together** in react but I am having trouble understanding how. I thought I could use template literals to achieve this purpose.

Here is the code below:
Login.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import LoginStyles from "../css/Login.module.css";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`${LoginStyles.background-color-main} d-flex align-items-center p-4`}>
        <Container fluid={true}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              Hello sir
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This gives me an error in the className, can anyone show me how I am supposed to properly use bootstrap and my own custom css modules together?

My Login.module.css is here:

```
.background-color-main {
    background-color: #87BFFF;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in property name `background-color-main` since you have used `-` casing. you should access the property by `LoginStyles["background-color-main"]`.

Here is the corrected code

```
import React from "react";
import LoginStyles from "../css/Login.module.css";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`${LoginStyles["background-color-main"]} d-flex align-items-center p-4`}>
        <Container fluid={true}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              Hello sir
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've update the same working code here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-morning-kjcm2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: what happens if you don't have the hyphens?

Comment: if you dont have `-` cases then I guess your current code should work fine.